# Editable tree view - changing type of editing field

Tags: qt, view, pyqt, pyqt5

I have dictionary like this:

```
{"key1": 1, "key2": 0, "key3": {"key": 1}, "dupa": None}
```

I would like to edit it as a tree view but I can't change `key1` to store a string.

I saw [editable model view example](https://github.com/pyqt/examples/tree/master/itemviews/editabletreemodel). And **edited** it to display my dictionary.
Here is example:

[image: My tree view]

Look at the read 'area' as u can expect there is no way to insert string in this filed.

**So my questions are:**

1. Witch class or function should I override to be allowed control edit item that is displayed (I wanna add control that allow change type and remove whole item or add new)? In other words: How can I be able to put string in this filed?
2. Where I can find originally definition of this function/class?

I used `qt` tag because You can answer my in C++ example, I can translate it to python.

#### My edited code: (ready to copy and run) but I think there is no need to look at it, to answer my questions.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QAbstractItemModel, QFile, QIODevice,
                          QItemSelectionModel, QModelIndex, Qt, QAbstractItemModel, QObject)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        self.parentItem = parent
        self.itemData = data  # it's also []
        self.childItems = []

    def child(self, row):
        return self.childItems[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.childItems)

    def childNumber(self):
        if self.parentItem is not None:
            return self.parentItem.childItems.index(self)
        return 0

    def columnCount(self):
        return len(self.itemData)

    def data(self, column):
        return self.itemData[column]

    def insertChildren(self, position, count, columns):
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.childItems):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            data = [None for v in range(columns)]
            item = TreeItem(data, self)
            self.childItems.insert(position, item)

        return True

    def appendChild_by_item(self, item):
        item.parentItem = self
        self.childItems.append(item)

    def appendChild_by_data(self, data):
        self.childItems.append(TreeItem(data, self))

    def insertColumns(self, position, columns):
        if position < 0 or position > len(self.itemData):
            return False

        for column in range(columns):
            self.itemData.insert(position, None)

        for child in self.childItems:
            child.insertColumns(position, columns)

        return True

    def parent(self):
        return self.parentItem

    def removeChildren(self, position, count):
        if position < 0 or position + count > len(self.childItems):
            return False

        for row in range(count):
            self.childItems.pop(position)

        return True

    def removeColumns(self, position, columns):
        if position < 0 or position + columns > len(self.itemData):
            return False

        for column in range(columns):
            self.itemData.pop(position)

        for child in self.childItems:
            child.removeColumns(position, columns)

        return True

    def setData(self, column, value):
        if column < 0 or column >= len(self.itemData):
            return False

        self.itemData[column] = value

        return True


class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, headers, data, parent=None):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

        rootData = [header for header in headers]
        self.rootItem = TreeItem(rootData)
        self.setupModelData(data, self.rootItem)

        print(self.rootItem.childCount())

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.rootItem.columnCount()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role != Qt.DisplayRole and role != Qt.EditRole:
            return None

        item = self.getItem(index)
        return item.data(index.column())

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return 0

        return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def getItem(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            item = index.internalPointer()
            if item:
                return item

        return self.rootItem

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.rootItem.data(section)

        return None

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid() and parent.column() != 0:
            return QModelIndex()

        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)
        childItem = parentItem.child(row)
        if childItem:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def insertColumns(self, position, columns, parent=QModelIndex()):
        self.beginInsertColumns(parent, position, position + columns - 1)
        success = self.rootItem.insertColumns(position, columns)
        self.endInsertColumns()

        return success

    def insertRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        success = parentItem.insertChildren(position, rows,
                                            self.rootItem.columnCount())
        self.endInsertRows()

        return success

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        childItem = self.getItem(index)
        parentItem = childItem.parent()

        if parentItem == self.rootItem:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentItem.childNumber(), 0, parentItem)

    def removeColumns(self, position, columns, parent=QModelIndex()):
        self.beginRemoveColumns(parent, position, position + columns - 1)
        success = self.rootItem.removeColumns(position, columns)
        self.endRemoveColumns()

        if self.rootItem.columnCount() == 0:
            self.removeRows(0, self.rowCount())

        return success

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)

        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)
        success = parentItem.removeChildren(position, rows)
        self.endRemoveRows()

        return success

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parentItem = self.getItem(parent)

        return parentItem.childCount()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role != Qt.EditRole:
            return False

        item = self.getItem(index)
        result = item.setData(index.column(), value)

        if result:
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)

        return result

    def setHeaderData(self, section, orientation, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if role != Qt.EditRole or orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return False

        result = self.rootItem.setData(section, value)
        if result:
            self.headerDataChanged.emit(orientation, section, section)

        return result

    def setupModelData(self, nested_dict, parent):
        print(nested_dict)
        for k, v in nested_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                parent.appendChild_by_data([k, None])
                self.setupModelData(v, parent.child(parent.childCount() - 1))
            else:
                parent.appendChild_by_data([k, v])


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """docstring for MainWindow"""

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=None)

        headersLabels = ("Key", "value")
        self.orginal_data = data
        print(data)
        self.m_model = TreeModel(headersLabels, data)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.m_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.m_view.setModel(self.m_model)

        self.testButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test")
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(self.testAction)

        self.buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(self.testButton)

        self.container_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.container_layout.addWidget(self.m_view)
        self.container_layout.addLayout(self.buttonLayout)

        self.container.setLayout(self.container_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)

    def testAction(self):

        selceteds = self.m_view.selectedIndexes()
        print(selceteds)
        for i in selceteds:
            item = self.m_model.getItem(i)
            print(item.data(i.column()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    _d = {"key1": 1, "key2": 0, "key3": {"key": 1}, "dupa": None}

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(_d)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*I Hope my English is understanding enough*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom [delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes) for editing your model items if you don't like the editor provided by the built-in delegate.

In your case, you'd need to subclass [QStyledItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#subclassing-qstyleditemdelegate) and reimplement methods [createEditor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor) (most likely you'd like to return `QLineEdit` from it), [setEditorData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#setEditorData) (to set the string converted from a number to the editor), [setModelData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#setModelData) (to set the number converted from string back into the model). Then you'd need to set your delegate to the view.

You might want to look at [StarDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html) example although your use-case seems simpler: you don't need to reimplement item painting.

Comment: Thank u. This was very helpful. I didn't understand for what are *Delegate classes.